# How to upload files to document library without using input type file using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I have kept my files inside SharePoint Hosted add in project folder,I want all the files to be uploaded in document library when app is getting deployed.

Please help.

Thanks in advance....!

Comment: could you elaborate your problem?

Comment: All my files are under images folder in my project as I don't want user to choose file for upload. That's why I am not using input type file,but I am not able to access the file by passing path of file(which is inside same project)

Comment: You can't access server-files or local-files with javascript. If thats what you want to do. Only thing you can do is to use AJAX to access a file via a server-sided language and then go on with javascript.